# Call Asp.Net button click event with ckEditor toolbar buttom

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor

I need to reach my codebehind click event from ckeditor button.
i am trying with this code for my custom ckeditor button(function () {

```
//Section 1 : Code to execute when the toolbar button is pressed
    var a = {
        exec: function (editor) {
            var testObj = editor.parentNode;
            var count = 1;
            while (testObj.getAttribute('id') != "form1") {
                testObj = testObj.parentNode;
            }
            testObj.getElementById('<%= btnUserControls.ClientID %>').click();
        }
    },
//Section 2 : Create the button and add the functionality to it
    b='usercontrols';
    CKEDITOR.plugins.add(b,{
        init:function(editor){
            editor.addCommand(b,a);
            editor.ui.addButton('usercontrols', {
                label:'User Controls',
                icon: this.path + 'ascx.png',
                command:b
            });
        }
    });
})();
```

But i think this code cannot reach my Asp.Net button.Where am i wrong ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to say exactly without knowing your *.aspx* code, but most probably the id of your form is not "form1" on client side. You can try modyfing your code like this:

```
...
var a = {
    exec: function (editor) {
        document.getElementById('<%= btnUserControls.ClientID %>').clic();
    }
}
...
```

or even like this:

```
...
var a = {
    exec: function (editor) {
        __doPostBack('<%= btnUserControls.UniqueID %>', '');
    }
}
...
```

Comment: They did not solve my problem.Also i tried this code  `__doPostBack('<%= btnUserControls.ClientID %>', 'OnClick');`

Comment: @BahadırYılmaz Have your tried with `__doPostBack('<%= btnUserControls.UniqueID %>', '');` (that was an obvious bug in my answer, I have edited it)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call server side click event for ASP.NET button then you need to execute script like this:  `__doPostBack('<%= btnUserControls.UniqueID %>', '');`
Note: that it is necessary to use UniqueID instead of ClientID.